# C# function to execute queries in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
public static DataSet execute_query(string query)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = DataAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.cn;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ds = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Are you constrained to .net 2.0?

Answer (score 14):

`SqlConnection` implements the `IDisposable` interface, and so does the `SqlDataAdapter` class - any type that implements `IDisposable` should have its `Dispose` method called; by disposing the connection you don't need to explicitly close it.

The best way to ensure `Dispose` gets called is to wrap the object in a `using` block, which is basically compiler magic for a `try/finally` block.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
    {
        DataSet result = new DataSet(); 
        adapter.Fill(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `SqlAdapter`+`DataSet` way will work on any version of .net - but it's also a pretty dated way to go about it, and since `DataSet` *also* implements `IDisposable`, returning it makes for awkward code, because normally it's the responsibility of the code that *creates* an `IDisposable` object to call its `Dispose` method - but if you do that (or wrap it in a `using` block), then the client code will run into an `ObjectDisposedException` when it tries to use the data set.

*Slightly* more advanced is the ADO.NET `SqlCommand`, which lets you create `SqlParameter` objects to send a *parameterized* command to the SQL Server. This puts the responsibility of dealing with parameters on the database server, where it belongs ([Greg Burghardt's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140315/23788) hints at this).

If you're not constrained to .net 2.0 then the next best thing would be LINQ-to-SQL, or Entity Framework (or NHibernate, or Dapper, depending on your needs): these more modern tools often eliminate the need to ever concatenate SQL strings, or even to explicitly create `SqlParameter` objects for a parameterized query - for example this:

```
public User GetById(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
    {
        return context.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Generates a SQL query similar to:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 Id, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, Gender 
FROM dbo.Users
WHERE Id = @id
```

...without ever needing to explicitly create a parameter or concatenate an arbitrary string into a bit of SQL - and C# looks so much better without SQL string literals all over the place! And the best part, it returns a `User` object ("entity") instead of a `DataTable`.

But it's great that you're starting with the lower-level stuff: lots of people *start* with Entity Framework and don't quite understand what's happening under the hood.

---

Other issues:

- The method being `static` hints at procedural-style. C# is multi-paradigm, but the overwhelmingly dominant one is the *object-oriented* one: by working with `static` methods, you're working with *types*, not *objects*. The difference will start showing when you start measuring things like *coupling* and *testability*.
- Method names should be `PascalCase`, so `execute_query` should be `ExecuteQuery`.
- `query` isn't an ideal name for a string containing an SQL statement, because starting in .NET 3.5 a *query* is a good name for an `IQueryable<T>` object that's actually building a *query* via a LINQ provider. Keep it simple: `sql` is a perfectly acceptable and descriptive name.

Comment: Can I ask why you do `connection.Open()` in the `using`? My understanding was this was implicitly called, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @RichardSimpson I don't see a reason for [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0(v=vs.110).aspx)'s constructor to automatically call `Open` - why would there be an `Open` and an `OpenAsync` method then? (besides that's also what the MSDN example does) ..it's the `Close` method that's implicitly called upon disposal of the object.

Comment: Ok, interesting. I've successfully used without the `connection.Open` (and for EF work too). Maybe something in the library is calling `.Open`.

Comment: @RichardSimpson EF is a completely different thing, instantiating the `DbContext` *does* open the connection (e.g. the `GetById` example in my answer), but then you're never dealing directly with an `SqlConnection`.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for clearing that up! Albeit slightly off topic.. but to finish off. With `DbContext`, any reason to still call `.Open`; or just added verbosity?

Comment: @RichardSimpson there is no `Open` member on a [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) instance =)

Comment: There is `DbContext.Database.Open` though

Answer (score 13):

There are two problems with this that are immediately apparent:

1. You are executing arbitrary SQL. This is a [SQL Injection flaw](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0926bc/sql-injection/). You'll want to use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. You are catching an exception and doing nothing with it. Malformed SQL, integrity constraint violations, or database connectivity issues will be swallowed, causing failures in your application with little hope of debugging it. Unless you can handle the exception properly **never never never never never** catch exceptions and do nothing with them.

   Future juan who has to debug a production issue will thank Past juan for this decision.

Comment: For the first, You don't know where he's getting his SQL from. Maybe he's only ever calling it with static SQL.

Comment: @Random32: You don't know that he is

Comment: @Random832 even if SQL injection was not a risk, concatenating SQL where statements together performs worse than parameterized queries because the SQL Server query analyzer has to generate a query plan for each new "argument" value. Of course, not a problem if it's only static SQL, but to Greg's point, this class has no idea what it's being passed and can't force client code ***not*** to concatenate queries together.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others this is open to SQL injection attack

To make it more generalized consider passing the connection string

Not going to have correct syntax every time.  Pass the SQL error back.

```
public static DataSet execute_query(string query, string conString, out string sqlError;)
{ 
    sqlError = string.empty;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        sqlError = ex.message;
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
    }
}
```